# Docker containers communication

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pyzmq

I'm striving to achieve the following :

- have multiple docker containers that perform some period tasks
- have a component running on the localhost that besides other tasks manages
  (starts/stops) the containers
- from time to time the services running
  within the containers need to publish the result. Therefore they bind
  to an exposed port using ZMQ and send the result.
- the component running on localhost subscribes to a specific port and listens on
  that.

The problem is that every container requires a specific/different port on the localhost network to bind to and publish the results. And this implies that I need to listen on all container ports.

Is it possible to listen to a single port and all containers publish their work there ?

If not , what would the options be ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to use ZMQ in container so, containers would publish work to zmq_container and from localhost you will be able to subscribe channel of zmq_contaniner as well (using one port)

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Publish results to central shared database (*like mysql or mongodb container*) from all and read from there
2. Publish results to central shared message queues (*like kafka container*) from all and read from there. (*kafka would be more powerful solution for reliable and real-time message exchange*)